# how to calculate standard error of variance parameter in fitlme

Tags: matlab

In matlab, after we have fitted a linear mixed model, how do we extract the standard error of the variance parameters?

```
load imports-85
tbl = table(X(:,12),X(:,14),X(:,24),'VariableNames',{'Horsepower','CityMPG','EngineType'});
lme = fitlme(tbl,'CityMPG~Horsepower+(1|EngineType)+(Horsepower-1|EngineType)');
cov = covarianceParameters(lme);
```

I know I can get the confidence limit of the standard deviation using

```
[cov,~,stat] = covarianceParameters(lme);
```

so if I can't extract what I want directly, perhaps I can transform the confidence limits (instead of reporting standard error)?

Answer (score 0):

If you just type `lme` to debug lme object you'll see there is a variable named *Res Std* having *Estimate* member

```
lme
.
.
Group: Error
    Name             Estimate    Lower     Upper 
    'Res Std'        3.226       2.9078    3.5789
```